# $F(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in C(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $f_1(t),\ldots,f_n(t)$ measurable on $\mathbb{R} \implies$ so is $F(f_1(t),\ldots,f_n(t))$

Tags: calculus, analysis, measure-theory

$F(x_1,\ldots,x_n) $ continuous on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f_1(t),\ldots,f_n(t)$ measurable on $\mathbb{R} \implies F(f_1(t),\ldots,f_n(t))$ measurable on $\mathbb{R}.$

When it says that  $F(x_1,...x_n) $ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^n$ that must mean that $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$.

I have the defition that a function $F:\mathbb{X}\to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable iff $A=\{x \in \mathbb{X}: F(x)>\alpha, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}\} \in B(\mathbb{X})$ - Borel set of $\mathbb{X}$

I am having difficulties with this, because this composition component is because me problems, I have proved that functions $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ that are continuous are measurable becauase I saw that $f^{-1}(\alpha,\infty)$ was an open set, because the inverse mapping of  continuous function on an open  set is indeed open. I would think, something similar would come into play here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably know (or you'll be able to retrieve or prove) that for $g$ measurable and $F$ continuous, $F \circ g$ is measurable. Hence you're left to prove that
$$g : t \mapsto (f_1(t), \dots, f_n(t))$$ is measurable. If $R \subseteq  \mathbb R^n$ is the set product of open intervals (let's call that a "pavé" which is the French word for it), i.e. $R=I_1 \times \dots \times I_n$, you have
$$g^{-1}(R) = f_1^{-1}(I_1) \cap \dots \cap f_n^{-1}(I_n)$$ which is measurable by our assumption on the measurability of $f_1, \dots, f_n$.

Now every open set $V \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is a countable union of such "pavés" $R_i$, and since
$$\displaystyle g^{-1}(V)=g^{-1} \left( \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty R_i \right) =\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty g^{-1}(R_i)$$ $g^{-1}(V)$ is measurable.

Comment: I have just one problem. This $V$, why is it a a countable union of such "paves", where is the proof behind this, or theory?(I have never come across this) I don't see how: lets take: $(1,2)\times(5,6)\times((2,5)\cup (7,8))$ how would I turn this into a union of (distinct?)"pavés" when there will, it seems to me, always be left out  individual points in attempts of doing this..